# Elegant code annotation for tutorials?

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface

I've been writing some tutorials, and I'm trying to figure out an elegant way to add line-by-line annotations to the code in the tutorials.

For example, suppose I have some code like this:

```
<h1>Demo of web page</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

I'd like to be able to add something (maybe a tooltip or some kind of lightbox effect) that allows me to present an explanation of each line to the reader, while still letting them see the line in context. The best I've been able to come up with is prose explanations that say things like "The line that starts with `<h1>` is a headline."

Anyone ever seen something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out docco:

http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/

It's written in CoffeeScript and generates an HTML doc from a source file breaking up the comment sections and the code. It sets up the comments as annotations for each section in one column and the corresponding properly highlighted code in the other column. I think it's a great simple way to grok annotations while keeping the code in context. Oh, and it also knows markdown.

Comment: That's *almost* exactly what I'm looking for. If I go this route, I'd probably use the Python port, Pycco. I'm not sure that it's worth the additional complexity the build step would add to my site, but it's the best I've seen. The functionality is exactly right. Thanks, Eliot.

Comment: (Just saw your Python port comment. Affirmative!)

Answer (score 0):

What about using title attributes?

```
<h1 title="your hover text">your text</h1>
```

Comment: That works for html, but not for other languages. Also, it makes the code itself more cluttered. But, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found something to rival Docco: the popover feature of Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover

I'm not sure that it will actually look good, but it seems like a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Old but good question, I was searching for similar things when I found this. There are tons of ways of doing HTML annotation, [see this article for a very nice listing and explanations](http://www.1729.com/blog/HtmlAnnotations.html).

If you want annotation that simply tells the user what each line does, I would write HTML comments for small pieces of code, and larger external annotations for large amounts of code. You could then parse them using custom JS to show prettier boxes if you so wish.

```
<h1>Heading</h1> <!-- A heading element -->
<p>paragraph</p> <!-- A paragraph element -->
<p>Paragraph with
    <b>Bold</b>      <!-- An inline Bold element -->
text</p>
```

For larger amounts of code, I would consider using something like the documentation that [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/) creates. Sure, it's for JavaScript but who says a similar one can't be done for HTML. As this was tagged with jquery-UI, you also might be interested in a [jQuery text annotater](http://pkedu.fbt.wur.nl/~koos/jQueryTextAnnotator/).

Comment: It's not really a ready answer for your lightboxy-like requirement, but I do think that it could be done DIY and no, I haven't seen a premade one - if I had the time I would hack together something.